# How to delete current element read in list by Python?

Tags: python, list

Here is what I exactly want:

```
A = [1,2,3]

for a in A:
    if a > 1:
        del a

print(A)
```

I want list a to be [1], however it will still be [1,2,3].

So my real goal is to delete current element I get now.

I know there is one usage of 'del' liking this:

```
A = [1,2,3]

for i, a in enumerate(A):
    if a > 1:
        del A[i]

print(A)
```

and list a will be [1,3] but not [1].

Because when I use

```
del a[1] #2
```

the orginally 3 in list A will be needed to use index 1 to get it from list A rather than using 2. So I can not delete it successfully.

How can I delete the current element in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B = filter(lambda x: x <= 1, A)
```

Then `B` is all elements that less than or equal 1 of `A`.

Comment: Thank you! This indeed does I want, but I more want to know how to delete current element I read.

Comment: @MarsLee : See my answer.

Comment: In fact you can't modify the elements of a list while it's being iterated. You could either save the indexes of elements or elements themselves you want to delete, then delete them after iterating finished. Or, Try iterate the list by index instead of elements. @PriyanshGoel

Comment: @liushuaikobe I think your this new thinking is better for me! Thank you!

Comment: @liushuaikobe : Yes you are correct. It is my mistake. Sorry my bad!

Answer (score 6):

It is almost never a good idea to change a collection you are iterative over. In many cases, a better way would be to select only these elements that you want in your new list.

A pythonesque way to do this is using list comprehension:

```
  a = [1,2,3]
  b = [x for x in a if x <= 1]

  print (b)
```

the `'[ .. for ... if ..]'` is a very nice syntax for all kinds of list operations like `map` and `filter`.

Notice that I complemented your filter predicate, because I select what has to stay, in stead of what has to be deleted.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you must be very careful while modifying the data structure if you are currently iterating over its elements. Python will give you an error if you try to delete elements from a list while iterating over the elements of the list. If you really want to modify the list, then use a different iteration strategy, e.g.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
n = len(A)
i = 0
while i < n:
    if A[i] > 1:
        del A[i]
        n -= 1
    else:
        i += 1
print(A)
```

This is one way to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [i for i in [1,2,3] if i<=1]
[1]
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x<=1, [1,2,3]))
[1]
>>>
```

all list elements that are `>1` are filtered out

Answer (score 0):

In your Code when you are trying to delete the value

```
del a
```

You actually were trying to delete a temporary variable **a** whose value is same as the value of A[X] . So the value in A still remains unaffected. If you want to delete the value from A, you can make use of

```
del A[X]
a.remove(value)
```

these methods will delete/remove the value from the List .